# Using myBatis with dynamic table name and object

Tags: java, mybatis

I'm about to create a dynamic SQL insert using myBatis, where the table name and the object holding the parameters are different. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO ${tablename} (column1, column2) VALUES (#{column1}, #{column2})
```

The interface method would be this:

```
@Insert(CREATE)
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id", flushCache = true)
public int write(String tablename, Object object) throws Exception;
```

Where the Object holds the field values:

```
class Object {
  int id;
  String column1;
  String column2;

  getters, setters...
}
```

Unfortunately I can't find out how to do this, the best and working way I found is when the table name is a property of the Object, so the myBatis can read the value in this way. For some practical reason I'd like to avoid this approach, maybe someone has a better idea? Thanks.

Comment: Use a Map of parameters. Put the table name and the other details into this map

Comment: Yes, the Map is a working solution too, but principally the same as if I put the table name into the object. The table name and the object properties have to be in the same value object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@Param` annotation like this

```
@Insert(CREATE)
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "object.id", flushCache = true)
public int write(@Param("tablename") String tablename,
                 @Param("object") Object object) throws Exception;
```

and query

```
INSERT INTO ${tablename} (column1, column2) VALUES (#{object.column1}, #{object.column2})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did not know it can be identified the object and its property in the query. And of course it worked at the keyProperty = "object.id".